# R1=load '/home/cloudera/desktop/emp.txt' using PigStorage(' , ') as (a:int, b:int); dump R1;

Tags: hive, apache-pig

```
Input : (a, (b,c))

Pig -x local 

R1=load '/home/cloudera/desktop/emp.txt' using PigStorage(' , ') as (a:int, b:int);       
dump R1;
```

When I executed this query,I did not get the desired output.I am only getting (,).

Answer (score 0):

Data have tuples . use below code .

`R1 = load '/home/cloudera/desktop/emp.txt'    as (t1: tuple(t1a: chararray, t: tuple(tb: chararray,tc: chararray)));`

`dump R1;`

or remove `'('` from data file and select correct data type...